# Use cell content as values for a weighted.average formula in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, weighted-average

I want to use the content of a cell as values of weighted.average formula in google sheet.

Example:

Cell A1 manually input values: 10,2,50,3,60,1
That means 10x2 + 50x3 + 60x1

Cell F1 put the formula: =weighted.average( *[contents from A1]* )
The result must be 38.33

I don't know how to concatenate this.

I've tried to use =weighted.average(text(A1)), =weighted.average(cell("contents",A1))

No results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

`=LAMBDA(ax,AVERAGE.WEIGHTED(QUERY(ax,"SELECT * SKIPPING 2"),QUERY({2^99;ax},"SELECT * SKIPPING 2 OFFSET 1")))(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(A1,",")))`

-

[image]

Comment: Hi, it worked! Thanks
How can I use an ARRAYFORMULA to copy down to cells below. I don't want to drag copy.

Comment: assuming Column A has the raw data then formula would be: =BYROW(A:A,LAMBDA(aix,IF(aix="",,LAMBDA(ax,AVERAGE.WEIGHTED(QUERY(ax,"SELECT * SKIPPING 2"),QUERY({2^99;ax},"SELECT * SKIPPING 2 OFFSET 1")))(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(aix,","))))))

Answer (score 1):

Another approach, based on adding a second additional delimiter every 2nd delimiter in the input and then splitting in two stages with a flatten in-between:

```
=arrayformula(lambda(splitrng,average.weighted(index(splitrng,,1),index(splitrng,,2)))(split(flatten(split(regexreplace(A1,"(\,.*?){2}","$0|"),"|")),",")))
```

Comment: Thanks, It worked as well! Is there a way to copy down to cells below. I don't want to drag copy.